# PowerShell script that should find disabled users that are not in a specific OU outputs users from that OU as well

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-management, organizational-unit

Hey I've got this cmdlet here:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {(distinguishedName -notlike "Disabled Users") -and (enabled -eq $false)} -searchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

I've built it to find disabled users that are not in the "Disabled Users" OU. (an OU within an OU)

But for some reason it returns not only the disabled users that are not in "Disabled Users", but the disabled users that are in it as well.

Why doesn't `(distinguishedName -notlike "Disabled Users")` work?

To make my structure clear:

```
Forest
    FirstOU
       users,groups,etc..
       Disabled Users OU
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The filter acts on the type of object you are trying to retrieve, in this case a User object.  Thus your query is returning any disabled users where the dn is not "Disabled Users".  It is applying the filter to the User objects, not the OUs.</strike>

Yes, of course...  The User dn will contain the string "Disabled Users" as BigHomie correctly pointed out.  The real problem was the lack of wildcard characters, since the User dn will not be exactly "Disabled Users"

Try this instead:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(Enabled -eq $false)} | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Disabled Users*') }
```

Comment: So how can I do it?

Comment: But the dn of the user *contains* the parent OU

Comment: Dang it, beat me with the edit! :) Yeah, I'd grab all the users first, and then filter with `Where-Object` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets and wildcards. Try

```
PS C:\Users\BigHomie> Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,dc=eng,dc=mit,dc=edu" -SearchScope Subtree -Filter {distinguishedname -notlike "*Disabled*"}
```

Proper Syntax was found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)

Comment: it's all good ;)

Comment: It does not output anything.. although I do have some users that should come out..

Comment: haha, perhaps your oneliner works as intended, and there *are* no disabled users outside the disabled OU?

Comment: @BigHomie nope. I have some disabled users that arent inside my Disabled Users OU.

Comment: did you set your `-SearchScope` to `Subtree`?

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote. I just copied it and edited it to match my domain. @BigHomie

Comment: @BigHomie got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't work because [DN attributes doesn't support wildcard matching in LDAP queries](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Clauses) (and `-like`/`-notlike` is useless without wildcards).

You'll simply have to retrieve all disabled users and then filter the unwanted accounts out from the result:

```
$Disabled = Get-ADUser -Filter { useraccountcontrol -bor 2 } -SearchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com"
$Filtered = $AllDisabledUsers |Where-Object {$_.distinguishedName -notmatch "OU=Disabled Users"}
```

The `{ useraccountcontrol -bor 2 }` is equivalent to a "pure" LDAP filter for disabled accounts:
`(&(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`